# ggbiplot for R version 3.1.0

Tags: ggbiplot

I'm trying to install ggbiplot on the version 3.1.0 of R from Github I get a warning message saying the package isn't available for R version 3.1.0.
Am I downloading the wring version of ggbiplot? Is there a newer version? Where? Or am I simply doing it wrong?

> install.packages("ggbiplot",lib="/Users/liza/Documents/ggbiplot-master")
>   Warning message:
>   package ‘ggbiplot’ is not available (for R version 3.1.0)

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
library(devtools)
install_github("vqv/ggbiplot")
```

Answer (score -1):

I just had this issue and installed R 2.15 and it worked!